# Sharing data with objects created with operator[](const size_t& i) - e.g. a complex vector container

Tags: c++, design-patterns, operator-overloading, data-sharing

when I want to share data I often get in a mess using the operator[] (const size_t& i) in c++.  I wanted to ask if there is a design pattern that I should be using - or a better way altogether.

Writing a complex vector container illustrates my problem - although I've had similar problems writing other containers.

This is the code that I want to write:

```
class complex; //forward declaration to my complex number container.

//my complex vector container 
class cvec{
    private:
      size_t m_size;  //The number of complex numbers in the vector
      /* I want my data stored 
       * real(0), imag(0), real(1), imag(1) ... real(m_size-1), imag(m_size-1) 
       * so that I can easily pass the data to blas routines - for example.
       */
      double* m_data;  // 2 * m_size
    public:
      //return a reference to constant complex number
      const complex& operator[](const size_t& i) const;  
      //return a reference to a complex number that points to m_data.
      //The user should be able to alter m_data by altering the returned complex number
      complex& operator[](const size_t& i);             
}
```

It mirrors exactly my `class vec` (which is just an array of doubles).

*My problem is how to manage the references to the complex numbers in a sane way when the data is shared in this manner.*

The way I am doing it at the moment feels ugly. I define my complex class like this:

```
class complex{
  private:
    double* m_data; //a pointer that always contains 2 elements
    bool    m_own;  //whether this class owns the data - or whether the data belongs to cvec
    void alloc_data(); //allocate the memory if m_own == true
  public:
    //A constructor when the complex number owns its data.
    complex(const double& x, const double& y) : m_own(true)
    { alloc_data(); m_data[0] = x; m_data[1]=y;}

    //A constructor when it does not
    complex(double* data) : m_own(false)
    { m_data = data;}

}
```

And then in the cvec class adding a set of references in a std::vector container like so

```
 class cvec{ 
 private:    
   ...  
   std::vector<boost::shared_ptr<complex> > m_complex_data;   
   void alloc_data() {  //I use calloc as I believe this is byte aligned while the new operator is not...
     if (m_size>0)
       m_data =  ( double* )  calloc(2*m_size, sizeof(double));

     m_complex_data.resize(m_size);
     for(size_t i=0;i<m_size;++i){
       //Pass a pointer to data to the new complex class
       boost::shared_ptr<complex> cptr(  new complex(m_data + 2*i) );
       m_complex_data[i] =  cptr ;
     }   
   } 
 public:   
   //Return the reference   
   const complex&
   operator[](const size_t& i) const
   {return *m_complex_data[i];}   
 }
```

This works but feels rather precarious.  I wanted to ask if there is a better way of managing references when you want to share data between classes.  Is there a design pattern that I should be using when sharing data in this way.

Many thanks,  Tom

Comment: What's wrong with shared_ptr<std::vector<std::complex>>?

Comment: Or, actually, what's wrong with std::vector<shared_ptr<std::complex<double> > >?

Comment: @ybunalobil, @David Hi, I want to store the data in a pointer so that I can pass it to the blas library easily (which takes a pointer to an array).  I don't want to have copy every element into an array before I can use the optimized functions. (Do I have to do that copy?)